# Android | AppWidget -Config Activity | Long running task

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-appwidget

I am developing an android app (only Widget) which displays some images from a remote location- say picasa or flickr.

So retrieving these images and preparing a bitmap from these resources is a long running task, for which i have written a service as suggested in android documentation.

I have developed this part and it is working fine.

The problem i am facing is with the Configuration Activity.
The Configuration Activity has a button. When you click on the button the configuration for the widget is saved.

Now what i want is when i click on the button ConfigActivity should be finished but at the same time there a call should be made to update the widget asynchronously.

Whats the best approach to do this. 
- Should i make a call to onUpdate method of the WidgetProvider.
- Start AsyncTask in the activity
- Something else

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start an `AsyncTask` and then call `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget` from that `AsyncTask`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) for detail.

Comment: OK- so after saving configuration on the button click i should call AsyncTask. But i want to finish the activity and then run this in background. so will the AsyncTask be alive even if i have finshed/closed the configuration activity.

Comment: Ah, if you want to finish the activity and run it in the background you should launch a Service that updates the widget rather than an AsyncTask.

Comment: Good, that would mean i'll have to pass a reference of the configuration activity to the service .. which in turn will fetch the widget and then will update it. But i feel there should be some better way of managing all this. I dont know but i am not gaining confidence in this approach.

Comment: Look at the API I link to: you do not need to pass a reference to the configuration activity to the Service. You need to pass the widget ID.